# Replace function or define by the text itself

Tags: c, vim, refactoring, automated-refactoring

How can I replace all occurence of

```
check_free_set_to_null(&pointer)
```

by

```
if (pointer)
{
    free(pointer)
    printf(pointer have been freed)
}
else
{
    printf(pointer couldnt had been freed)
    return (1)
}
```

maybe using some sort of

{1} = check_free_set_to_null(CONTENT)

```
  if ({1})
    {
        free({1})
        printf({1} have been freed)
    }
    else
    {
        printf({1} couldnt had been freed)
        return (1)
    }
```

how could I do that ?
(take note thats its not exactly what that have to be replaced, its just an example)
Im not looking for the compiler to interpret it as multiple line, im looking for modifying the file.

Comment: Note: a check of `if (pointer)` is not needed before calling `free(pointer)`.  `pointer = NULL; free(pointer);` is OK.

Comment: @chux first setting it to null, later call `free`?

Comment: @tilz0R Simply short demo code.  `free(NULL);` is OK.  OP's need for `if (pointer)` before `free()` is dubious.

Comment: Calling `free` on `NULL` ptr is fine as @chux pointed out. `free` does not do anythng if pointer is `NULL`. more at `man 3 free`

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros for this job.

```
#define check_free_set_to_null(pointer) if (pointer) { \
    free(pointer)\
    printf(pointer have been freed)\
} else {\
    printf(pointer couldnt had been freed)\
    return (1)\
}
```

Comment: It need to be inline on the file. How can I only activate this macro and generate the c file ?

Comment: @user6714088 with this approach, compiler will put it inline.

Comment: It need to be inline on a new or the same file for more editing without putting other define inline then

Comment: As title stated, I need to put the define or fonction text inline.

Comment: No, this is not achievable in that way. You have to open your file and do for exmaple `preg` replace in a file itself.